# data model to support user defined templates, input fields may be string, int or date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, data-modeling

I'm having trouble getting my head around modeling the entities for a couple of scenarios. One of which is a legacy licensing system that needs to be refreshed, the other system would be unrelated but what they have in common is that the user would define a number of input fields that may take string, int or date (or possibly even other datatypes). The number and arrangement of those fields is not known at compilation time.

I will try to elaborate further with a more concrete example.

The license system lets the user define a set of products, each product has a collection of features and when generating a license key each feature has a value defined. e.g. Spellchecker feature could be on, or off in the license key. There are also product templates that let the user define the default value for features (e.g. think along the lines of a product SKU, where you may have Pro version which enables more features, Lite version with many things turned off).

The ultimate goal is really to define a product, and its features. A product template defines the values for each feature for a product SKU. And the when creating a new license key the user picks a product template to get the default values for features from the template, but each value can be overridden. Ultimately the license key tells the software which features should be enabled, and may pass some values into the software. The product and product templates define which features exist, and which values / data types can be input into the license.

An example product template might look like (hypothetical product):

```
Product: int (productID)
Template name: string
Feature1-SpellCheck: bool
Feature2-Tables: bool
Feature3-ExpiryDate: date
Feature4-DefaultFont: string
```

An example license might look like:

```
Product: TextEditor
Template name: Text Editor Pro
Feature1-SpellCheck: on
Feature2-Tables: on
Feature3-ExpiryDate: 1/1/2020
Feature4-DefaultFont: Helvetica
```

The part I'm having difficulty with is how to model the Feature, and Product Templates in a way that a user could create a new product and add features with the flexibility to define different data types for each feature. By defining a product the user is creating a list of features that can be enabled / disabled or have some kind of value specified. I'm not sure how to best model this data type, since there are at least 3 different data types a user might choose when adding a feature to a product (string, int, date etc.)

In the legacy system this was modeled by entities TemplateAttribute and LicenseAttribute which could take both an integer value, and a string value (dates were stored as an integer). AttributeValue and AttributeValueS. This legacy system dates back to around year 2000 and was built with VB forms and SQL. And what I'm trying to figure out is whether there is a better way to represent this relationship in newer technology like entity-framework class based model. I would like to write this solution in ASP.NET MVC with EF for persisting data.

**Image of the legacy data model:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8OcY.jpg

```
Note that ProductAttribute.Type has FK relationship to Types.TypeName.
That's where the Attributes and the data Types are linked.
```

So far the two ways I could see to solve it would be:

- reproduce the legacy model verbatim, taking both an int and string value for each feature (attribute)
- have a separate collection for each datatype, e.g. product would include featurestring, featureint, featurebool etc.

Neither of these solutions seem elegant to me, I'm wondering if anyone may have a better idea on how this could be modeled. Perhaps there is a more generic way, or a similar pattern I can look at for ideas. Most data model tutorials I have seen use very flat relationships, whereas in this instance the model is kind of supporting a user defined model for an object (product / features) on top of itself.

Comment: Sorry for the long question, I found this challenging to express

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to please data modeling critics, you may consider a separate table for each data type.